# Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory (process)

Tags: node.js, npm, process, browserify

I am using browserify v17.0.0 in order to use node.js modules in a web project. This was working fine until today when I attempted to convert src file as follows:

```
call browserify web-src.js -o web.js

Error: Can't walk dependency graph: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '${home_dir}\process'
    required by ${home_dir}\node_modules\mysql2\lib\pool.js
```

(very odd as I haven't changed the version of browserify or any of the code!).

The process module is present in node_modules, and I have tried clearing npm cache and completely reinstalling with `npm install`

If I disable all imports that use the mysql2 library above, then I can compile web.js successfully with the above commands. However, when I attempt to serve this file with an express.js web server,  there is an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')
    at Object.<anonymous> (web.js:122518)
    at Object.<anonymous> (web.js:122527)
    at Object.780../lib/telegram (web.js:122527)
    at o (web.js:1)
    at web.js:1
    at Object.<anonymous> (web.js:171670)
    at Object.<anonymous> (web.js:171981)
    at Object.944.../database/database-functions (web.js:171981)
    at o (web.js:1)
    at web.js:1
```

Which refers to the following line in the compiled code:

```
const majorVersion = parseInt(process.versions.node.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - I should not have been trying to use the node.js process API in a browser context.

Turns out there were code changes which imported modules using the process API and this is how the error manifested itself.

Strangely enough, when the mysql2 package was imported, this prevented compilation.
Once this was removed, web.js compiled but telegram API package caused the runtime error also seen above